# Can't merge "Free Space" with Macintosh partition

Tags: high-sierra, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

[image]

[image]

I have deleted a messed up bootcamp install and now I am stuck with 50 GB in "Free Space" that I am unable to "delete" or merge with my Macintosh partition. Anyway to do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
diskutil apfs resizeContainer /dev/disk1 0
```

The command above fixed it :)